# Calculate sale price taking the final price with discount in PHP

Tags: php, calculator

I have a purchase price, then I increase the 20% profit. The problem is that if my supplier makes a 5% discount on the purchase, then I discount that 5% discount at my normal purchase price and this new discount purchase price will boost the 20% profit. But I can not calculate the normal sale price.

Discount: 5%

Profit: 20%

372.93 - Purchase price without discount.

354.29 - Purchase price with discount.

?????? - Sale price.

425.15 - Sale price with Profit.

**This is my PHP code:**

```
<?php
 $discount = 5;
 $profit = 1.20;
 $purchase = 372.93;

 $product_purchase = $purchase - ($purchase * ($discount / 100)); // 354.2835
 $product_sale = 0; //??????????
 $product_sale_final = $product_purchase*$profit; //425.1402

 echo "Purchase: ".$product_purchase."<br>";
 echo "Product Sale: ".$product_sale."<br>";
 echo "Product Sale Final: ".$product_sale_final."<br>";
 echo "Discount: ".$discount."%";
?>
```

I hope someone can help me, I have many hours trying to find the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well if you want to bost *your profit* on seller discount, the buyer price shouldn't be based on the discount at all. If you don't have the original seller price at hand, you're out of luck and the discount will be forwarded to the buyer based on your +20% formula.

Comment: I'm not sure but,  isn't the 'normal sale price' the purchase price without any discount?

Comment: @ErrolChavesMoya Wow, this is correct, it's as simple as this: $product_sale = $purchase*$profit; - Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @David Noriega, happy to help.